# Buscar registros existentes en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Deseo buscar un cliente por cédula en mi base de datos y que al encontrarlo lo muestre, acá el código del formulario:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <p align="center">Cedula :<input name="cedula" type="text" value="" 
    id="celcliente">
    <input name="consultar" type="submit" id="consultar" value="Revisar">
</form>
```

y acá tengo el PHP que estoy empleando

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["celcliente"]) &&
    !empty($_GET["celcliente"])){

    $cedula = $_GET["celcliente"];
    $query = "SELECT celcliente, idcliente, nombreCliente FROM cliente WHERE 
              idcliente LIKE '%$celcliente%' ORDER BY nombreCliente ASC";
    $ejecutar = mysql_query($query);
    $total_reg = mysql_num_rows($ejecutar);
    if($total_reg > 0){
        while($registros = mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
            echo $registros['celcliente']."-";
            echo $registros['idcliente']."-";
            echo $registros['nombreCliente']."-";

        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No se encontraron resultados...!";
    }   
}

?>
```

El tema es que no encuentra los datos

Comment: al final de tu post dices: El tema es que encuentra los datos, buscas que los encuentre o no?

Comment: `$_GET["celcliente"]` <-- celcliente o `cedula`??? ¿Cual es el `name` del input?... Además, lectura obligatoria: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiar estas líneas:

```
if(isset($_GET["celcliente"]) &&
  !empty($_GET["celcliente"])){

$cedula = $_GET["celcliente"];
```

**POR:**

```
if(isset($_GET["cedula"]) &&
  !empty($_GET["cedula"])){

$cedula = $_GET["cedula"];
```

O de lo contrario solo cambia en tu **html**

```
<input name="cedula" type="text" value="" id="celcliente">
```

**POR:**

```
<input name="celcliente" type="text" value="" id="celcliente">
```

Ahora te explico. Cuando creas un formulario los atributos **name** de cada input, textarea, select son las llaves de las variables $_GET y $_POST que recibes del lado del servidor. Es decir si tu campo de texto se llama cedula aunque el id sea id sea celcliente en $_GET solo recivirás cedula. Si quieres hacer una prueba intenta poner un

```
exit(print_r($_GET));
```

Al comienzo de tu archivo php, y verás de lo que hablo.